# How to keep pjsip connection alive?

Tags: c, pjsip

I searched through pjsip code but found no clue for such "keepAlive" function. 
How do I do this? I'm using `pjproject-2.1.0`.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://github.com/WachterJud/qaul.net/blob/2f3fa8d106c310a67d14689ae5ad7f554c5948bc/pjproject_android/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/pjsua_app.c

Just call `pjsua_acc_set_registration()` on each account.

```
void keepAliveFunction(int timeout)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<(int)pjsua_acc_get_count(); ++i) {
    if (!pjsua_acc_is_valid(i))
        continue;

    if (app_config.acc_cfg[i].reg_timeout < timeout)
        app_config.acc_cfg[i].reg_timeout = timeout;
    pjsua_acc_set_registration(i, PJ_TRUE);
    }
}
```